# Retrieve database data linked to PersonID and show in listbox

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access

So i've created a application that is linked to a MS Acces database. I have a login system and when the login is succesful, their Personal data is displayed in some textboxes. One of these textboxes shows their PersonID (the ID for acces database).

User can make a appointment. This will be written in the database under UserID - Appointment date - Treatment. I want to retrieve this info and shows it into my listbox. But don't know why, because it needs to only retrieve the data that is linked to the logged in UserID ofcourse.

I have something like this but i'm stuck right now.

```
connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        string afspraken = "select * from Appointments where PersonID = '" + textBox4.Text + "'";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        listBox2.DataSource = reader;
        connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        string afspraken = "select * from Appointments where PersonID = '" + textBox4.Text + "'";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);

        foreach (DataRow Dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Dr["COLUMNNAME"].ToString());
        }

        con.Close();
```

Try This ...

Comment: Thanks but it's not SQL and i've already set the datasource for the login part:


            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select * from Inlogsysteem where PersoonID= '" + textBoxUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + textBoxPassword.Text + "'";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Now Check its Worked.... you have to take data in datatable and by using foreach loop add the items in ListBox ... We Have to Just Implement logic whatever connection it is.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ExecuteReader: property Connection is not initialised.

Comment: Okey, I fixed that error. Now I get the following error:



An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

The assignmenttext is not set for the assignment object.

?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Don't know what to do with that link. lol. Absolute beginner reporting in.